# Make button vertically centered within td

Tags: html, css

Here is example:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="background: lightgreen; vertical-align: middle">
      <button type="button">b1</button>
    </td>
    <td style="background: yellow; vertical-align: middle">
      <button type="button">b2</button>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="2"></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

And here is JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jhqjumgL/1/

I guess it's self-explaining, i need here all buttons vertically centered, but button paired with textarea for some reason decided to rest at bottom, any idea how to solve ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to vertically align the `textarea` as well:

```
button, textarea {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

***Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jhqjumgL/2/***

Answer (score 0):

The `vertical-align` property to sets the vertical alignment of an element.

So, you give it to element display vertically like following :

```
button{
   vertical-align : middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: lightgreen;">
      <button type="button">b1</button>
    </td>
        <td style="background: yellow;">
      <button type="button">b2</button>
      <textarea cols="40" rows="2" style="vertical-align: middle"></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```